# need help sharepoint 2010 development

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

i need some Help About SharePoint 2010. after one week  my interview is schedule anyone one have SharePoint 2010 development basic tutorial how i create content-type  and how to create Farm aspx page in SharePoint using visual studio how to create list using VS. i have many questions about share point development please help. what is important topics of sharepoint development.i need basics ebook i have download sharepoint development ebook but i can't understand how do this. please help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to view a few introductory videos on the topic: pluralsight is a great source of professional videos: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint-work-using-creating-types

But youtube can often get you the basics as well.